Errors while using firebase
Hi i am developing on ionic cordova and we are using firebase to listen to events. The existing flow is, we generate a payment link , open it using a inapp browser (for android) or SFViewController (for ios), and listen to firebase events for current status. When the status is favourable we close the inapp browser.
However, while the android implementaiton works fine. We get the following errors

@firebase/firestore: Firestore (8.6.2): FIRESTORE (8.6.2) INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Unexpected state

I have tried searching for the above issue got some links which tell to upgrade or downgrade the verions for firebase which i tried and it failed
please help.
code snippet
function startListeningMultisafePayUpdatesIos(data) {
                $timeout(() => {
                    const orderId = data.orderId;
                    firebase.firestore().collection("multisafepayPayments").doc(orderId).set({
                        financialStatus: "",
                        orderId: orderId,
                        transactionJson: {}
                    }).then(() => {
                        unsubscribeMultisafePayListener = firebase.firestore()
                            .collection("multisafepayPayments")
                            .doc(orderId)
                            .onSnapshot(function (doc) {
                                if (doc.exists) {
                                    console.log("doc data exisits");
                                    console.log(doc.data);
                                    // let message = doc.data();
                                    // if (typeof message.paymentKeyData !== "undefined" && message.paymentKeyData !== null) {
                                    //     let paymentJsonData = decodeURIComponent(message.paymentKeyData);
                                    //     if (paymentJsonData !== null) {
                                    //         submitPayment(JSON.parse(paymentJsonData));
                                    //         SafariViewController.hide();
                                    //     }
                                    // } else if (typeof message.reloadFrame !== "undefined" && message.reloadFrame === 'True') {
                                    //     SafariViewController.hide();
                                    //     reloadControls();
                                    // }
                                }
                            });
                    }).catch((error) => {
                        console.error("Multisafepay Payment error: ", error);
                        // navigator.notification.alert(
                        //     error.message || error,
                        //     function () { },
                        //     capitalizeFirstLetter("There was an error using apple pay for this payment"),
                        //     $translate.instant("OK")
                        // );
                    });

                    let loadFrameUrl = data.url;

                    SafariViewController.isAvailable(function (available) {
                        if (available) {
                            SafariViewController.show({
                                url: loadFrameUrl,
                                hidden: false,
                                animated: false
                            }, function (result) {
                                if (result.event === 'opened') {
                                    console.log('opened');
                                } else if (result.event === 'loaded') {
                                    console.log('loaded');
                                } else if (result.event === 'closed') {
                                    console.log('closed');
                                }
                                $scope.freedompayInterimLoading = false;
                            }, function (msg) {
                                navigator.notification.alert(
                                    msg,
                                    function () { },
                                    capitalizeFirstLetter("There was an error using multisafepay for this payment"),
                                    $translate.instant("OK")
                                );
                                // $scope.freedompayInterimLoading = false;
                            });
                        } else {
                            navigator.notification.alert(
                                "SFViewController not available",
                                function () { },
                                capitalizeFirstLetter("There was an error using apple pay for this payment"),
                                $translate.instant("OK")
                            );
                            // $scope.freedompayInterimLoading = false;
                        }
                    });
                }, 1000);
            }

